# Method to initialize multiple linked list

Tags: c

I am trying to create a method to initialize multiple linked lists by passing a string value to the initialize method and then assigning that string to a new linked list.

For example, if I pass `Initialize('list1')` to the Initialize method, I need it to initialize a new linked list called list1.

Here's my structure that I need each list to use and the initialize method:

```
struct node {
    int number;
    struct node *next;
};
typedef struct node item;

void Initialize(char *name) {

}
```

I don't know how to start creating the initialize method though. Please help.

Comment: I don't think you can create variable names at runtime. What you can do is create array of lists. Every time you create new list you refer to the index of an array.

Comment: Alright, how then would I initialize, say 5 of these linked lists, not at runtime?

Comment: you simply declare 5 lists and initialize them manually one by one.

Comment: @user2961919: What is "not at runtime" supposed to mean?

Comment: Would it just be `item* list1, list2, list3, list4, list5;` in the `Initialize()` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good place to start would be realizing that your question doesn't make sense as-is. `Initialize()` can't "initialize a linked list called X". What `Initialize` *can* do is allocate and return an `item*`.

```
item* Initialize() {
  /* Call malloc() here, among other things. */
  /* And what do you want to initialize the number to? Where should that come from? */
}
```

Then,

```
int main(void) {
  item* list1=Initialize();
  /* ... */
}
```

Note that this initializes *one* node - a "list" of one isn't very useful, is it?